# [React Native + Expo]: Save big amount of data

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to save big amount of data. The data is a JSON file which allow user to use application offline.

I can’t save it to AsyncStorage because this JSON is more than 6mb. And as I know I can’t increase this param without eject from expo.

I tried to use Expo FileSystem but don’t know how to save. In official doc I didn’t find good example for saving json.

I don’t want use sqlite, because it makes implementation much complicated?

So, do you know how I can save more than 6mb of data?

Thanks.

duplicate: https://forums.expo.io/t/save-big-amount-of-data/34336